How to perform data-driven choice of sample size
Say I want to compare the result of 2 regression model. One is the reference model and the second one is the new model, which I want to know if it performs better. Each model is evaluated with the pearson's correlation and, given that the datasets are dependent and that test data are the same, I want to get the confidence interval of the paired difference to see if it contains zero or not.
But I don't know the variance of the difference in advance, nor do I know what is the right sample size, so I came up with the following:
min_diff_to_detect
all_pearsons_ref = []
all_pearsons_new = []
alpha = 0.05

Loop until loop breaks -> for current loop n:
    train_ref, train_new, test_data = get_new_data_split()

    ref_model = train_ref_model(train_ref)
    pearson_ref = evaluate( ref_model(test_data) )
    all_pearsons_ref.append(pearson_ref)

    new_model = train_new_model(train_new)
    pearson_new = evaluate( new_model(test_data) )
    all_pearsons_new.append(pearson_new)

    differences = all_pearsons_new - all_pearsons_ref # pairwise differences
    confidence_interval = compute_CI(0, np.std(differences), n, alpha)

    if min_diff_to_detect not in confidence_interval:
        if np.mean(differences) not in confidence_interval:
            return are_different
        return are_not_different

train_data are dependent and test_data are the same for both models. The idea is to use the data to look for optimal number of loop N. otherwise N would be guessed and could either be too small to have enough statistical power, or too big and would take too long to train.
However, there is also the possibility that the variance fluctuates a lot in the early loops, causing possible false detection of the min_diff_to_detect. This latter point can maybe be mitigated by introducing a minimum number of loop before evaluated the if conditions, but this feels arbitrary and ultimately, I don't know if this approach is valid.
I also know about bootstrapping, but it would require a lot of training to be effective.
So, can the first if condition be improved to avoid errors ? and ultimately, is this a valid approach ?

You touch on several topics: you pair performance metrics to achieve variance reduction by using common random numbers (common test train split), see Wikipedia on variance reduction. Additionally, you try to early stop your comparison which is definitely affected by the variance of your performance estimator. Since you do not know the effect size ( mean difference of performance estimators and the variance of it) you are having trouble of early stopping by accident. If you know nothing it is tough and I would advocate Bootstrapping...

Or maybe there is some literature on sequential testing and the optimal stopping, sequential decision making under uncertainty

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_stopping

Is there a reason why you should not simply compare RMSE (or MSE, etc) of the two models?

@Ggjj11: pairing the data seems to be the proper way to me, given the dependency of the data, so I am not sure why you raise that point. Then, early stopping by accident is actually my main concern. I am currently reading about "optional stopping" and "sequential testing", which apparently are precisely trying to handle that type of situation, but so far it only mentioned p-value threshold adaptation. I am surprised that simple method like rolling average over variances is not even mentioned (so far), which seems a good way to stabilize the variance to me (?)

@mkt: does it have any advantages ? I mean, I will also need to get a sample of size n of them, and therefore end up with the same problem (?)

I think I understand your situation better now. Are you basically asking how to select a value for k in k-fold cross-validation?

the whole process is a nested cross-validation I would say, with the outer loop being my main loop, and with 2 inner loop (one for each model training) done with cross-validation. So i am asking for the k-fold of the outer loop actually.

Btw, I am not testing the significance of the differences until the the min_diff_to_detect  is considered detectable actually. So I am not repeatedly looking at the data, in a sens, though I still use them to estimate the variance. Maybe this reduces possible false detection.
